# Open Android app from a progressive web app

Tags: android, android-intent, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I need to open the WhatsApp Android app from within a Progressive Web App (PWA). This works but only if a phone number is available:

HTML

```
<a href="intent://send/0123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">?">OPEN WHATSAPP ANDROID</a>
```

Is there an intent to just open the app? (like if you would tap the app icon on the home screen)

Answer (score 1):

If you find the package name and component of the main activity for WhatsApp, you can do like,

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(whatsAppPkg, whatsAppActivity);
startActivity(new Intent().setComponent(cn));
```

If you have the WhatsApp APK, you can use a tool like [`apktool`](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to decompile it and look for the info you need in the manifest. Might take a little experimentation to find the right activity. Also note this could break at any time when the WhatsApp app is updated and could be different for different versions of the app.

It's also *possible* that WhatsApp has a public action-name based intent filter. You'd have to refer to their documentation to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going the URL Scheme route. If anyone knows a working **URL Scheme for GMAIL** - please let me know.

Comment: No, I'm basically asking the if WhatsApp is installed. Here is an example for those who are interested in using it: `window.open('whatsapp://send?text=Hello', '_blank')` - <a href="..." works as well of course. That link will open WhatsApp or WhatsApp for Business on Android (8.1) from a WebApp/Website. If it's not installed, nothing happens unless you add fallbacks or callbacks to the link.